# How to draw curved line chart using Canvas Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, charts, android-jetpack-compose

Does anyone know how to drawLine with curved every corner using canvas in Jetpack Compose?

I have achieved this using `Canvas.drawPoints()`:

[image]

but I want to make every corner to curved something like this:

[image]

Very appreciate any helps!

Comment: check out [this article](https://medium.com/falabellatechnology/jetpack-compose-canvas-8aee73eab393), especially part about "Bezier curves".